# I want to put a comment that will let me get to a different block of code in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I think I could maybe use cref in the xml comments.

I also found a devious way using the nameof operator.

```
string fakeString = nameof( NewForm.HandleCommandLineArgments ); // use go to definition to get to NewForm.HandleCommandLineArgments
```

Any other ideas?

**Update:**
I realize how to go to definition, ideally I wouldn't have to add "string fakeString".  I thought cref is a bit of a bummer since I thought it could only be in xml comments at the top of the method, but you can put them anywhere.

**I'm going with:**

```
        /// <see cref="NewForm.HandleCommandLineArgments">
        PipeClient.SendSimpleStringMessage( "scriptcode", "[Arguments]" + commandLineArguments );
```

Comment: Right click on it, select go to definition...

Comment: Put cursor on type and press F12 key.

Comment: Actually, xml doc comments in the wrong place, like in code, can also result in a diagnostic (but not entirely sure whether that’s VS doing it or R#). If that statement is part of larger code, a nicer way to do it would be to create a method `SendCommandLineArguments` method taking a string, containing only that `PipeClient` call. That method’s xml doc can then mention that the arguments it sends are handled by that referenced method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017, you can just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or whatever shortcut is assigned to `Edit/Go To All`) to go to any type. ReSharper has similar functionality even in earlier Visual Studio versions.

More should not be necessary; and variables like your `fakeString` are really a code smell (and may even cause build/maintenance issues due to "unused variable" diagnostics).

If it's something that is related to the method, it's also perfectly acceptable to include links in the XML Doc via `<see cref="..."/>` and/or `<seealso cref="..."/>`.